# Converting a while loop to a for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to convert this while loop into a for loop, I know it seems simple, but I am having a mental block and am unsure where to even begin, if anyone could help me figure this out it would be greatly appreciated :-) thank you for reading

```
counter = 0
while(counter < 10):
    num1 = float(input("Enter number 1: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter number 2: "))
    if num1 > num2:
        print(num1)
    else:
        print(num2)
    counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: do you mean for int i =0; i < 10; i++ (though i'm not sure about the exact python syntax, int c# that would do it)?

Comment: yeah, I mean i need the "while(counter < 10):" part to change to a "for" loop. I am unsure what syntax to use as well

Comment: You should seriously consider reading the python doc over at https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop, the first example is exactly what you're looking for but a it loops from 0 to 3 instead of 0 to 10

Answer (score 0):

The basic format is :

```
for x in range(start,end,increment):
    ...
```

You may omit the **start ( by default its 0 )** and **increment ( by default its +1 )** values.

So, you may use:

```
for counter in range(0,10,1):
    ...
```

or simply

```
for counter in range(10):
    ...
```